# Labeling of Bland Altman Plot in RStudio

Tags: r, plot, printing

I would like to label the number of the LoA and the mean on the plot
and change the color of the dashed lines.
Does sb know the code?
[image]

This is my code right now:

```
HF_plot1 <- bland.altman.plot(MA_subset$HF_Uhr, 
                           MA_subset$HF_VNS, graph.sys = "ggplot2",
                           mode = 1)
                          
print(HF_plot1 + ggtitle("Bland-Altman-Plot for Heart Frequency")+
        theme(plot.title = element_text(size=15, face= "bold", 
                                        hjust = 0.5))+
        labs(x="Means of HF between Garmin Venu 2 & VNS analysis [bpm]",
             y ="Difference of HF between Garmin Venu 2 & VNS analysis [bpm]")+
        theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size= 9, hjust = 0.5))+
        theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size= 8, hjust = 0.5, 
                                          lineheight= 1)))
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: dput(data)
structure(list(HF_Uhr = c(66L, 62L, 62L, 63L, 70L, 62L, 69L, 
62L, 60L, 62L, 68L, 61L, 72L, 74L, 79L, 55L, 71L, 70L, 85L, 84L, 
64L, 69L, 69L, 74L, 79L, 63L, 77L, 79L, 85L, 73L), HF_VNS = c(65.3, 
61.4, 60.8, 62.9, 69.4, 61.1, 68.4, 62.6, 59.5, 62.9, 68.4, 60.1, 
78.2, 73.1, 78.8, 58.8, 68.5, 70.6, 84.4, 84.7, 61.3, 69.4, 67.4, 
82.2, 72.8, 62.6, 77.4, 78.8, 87.2, 73.2)), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 2):

Since the dashed lines already exist as a geom layer in the `HF_plot1` object, you would need to add the colors in situ to that object. Adding labels to the limits of agreement (LoA) lines requires adding a `geom_text` layer - you can get the y values for the LoA lines from the data already present in the `HF_plot1` object.

Here I'm using some data that resembles your own (see footnote)

```r
library(BlandAltmanLeh)

HF_plot1 <- bland.altman.plot(MA_subset$HF_Uhr, 
                              MA_subset$HF_VNS, graph.sys = "ggplot2",
                              mode = 1)

# Change the colors of the geom_hline layer in situ
HF_plot1$layers[[2]]$aes_params$colour <- c('red', 'gray', 'red')

HF_plot1 + ggtitle("Bland-Altman-Plot for Heart Frequency")+
        theme(plot.title = element_text(size=15, face = "bold", 
                                        hjust = 0.5)) +
        labs(x="Means of HF between Garmin Venu 2 & VNS analysis [bpm]",
             y ="Difference of HF between Garmin Venu 2 & VNS analysis [bpm]")+
        theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size= 9, hjust = 0.5))+
        theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size= 8, hjust = 0.5, 
                                          lineheight= 1)) +
  geom_text(data = data.frame(y = HF_plot1$layers[[2]]$data[-2,]),
            aes(x = 45, y = y, label = round(y, 2)),
            hjust = 0, vjust = -0.2, size = 6)
```

[image]

---

**Footnote - made up data**

```r
set.seed(1234)
MA_subset <- data.frame(HF_Uhr = rnorm(200, 70, 15))
diffvals <- 2 * rnorm(200)^1.5 * sample(c(-1, 1), 200, TRUE)
MA_subset$HF_VNS <- MA_subset$HF_Uhr + diffvals
```

Comment: Do you know how to also add the value of the mean difference on the plot? (on top of the grey dashed line)

Comment: Yes, change `data = data.frame(y = HF_plot1$layers[[2]]$data[-2,])` to `data = data.frame(y = HF_plot1$layers[[2]]$data$yintercept)`

Comment: Thank you!  I also would like to label the dashed lines with +1.96 SD,Mean,-1.96 SD. I tried  {geom_text(data = data.frame(y = RMSSD_plot1$layers[[2]]$data$yintercept, row.names = c("+1.96 SD","Mean","-1.96 SD"))} , but it didn't display... is there another method?